# How to create a blocks matrix on Python?

Tags: python, matrix, block

I wanna create something like this:

```
import numpy as np
M=np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
A=np.matrix([[M,M],[M,M]])
print(A)
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: In what way does it not work? What output are you getting and how does that compare with your expectations?
I would try `A = np.hstack((np.vstack((M, M)), np.vstack((M, M))`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky, you have to construct each column separately, then combine the columns:

```
A = np.concatenate([np.concatenate([M, M]), 
                    np.concatenate([M, M])], axis=1)
#matrix([[1, 2, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 3, 4],
#        [1, 2, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 3, 4]])
```